# Intent put extra always null

Tags: java, android, string, android-intent, null

So I have 3 activities: `firstlog`, explanation, `mapsactivity`. When the app is opened it goes to `firstlog` then explanation then `mapactivity` then `firstlog` and when it's there I want it to make it so that when you go from `firstlog` it transfers you to maps activity. So I tried just passing a value then saving it with shared preferences, value is always `null`... Tried saving the `sharedpref` in maps and checking it in `firstlog`, always default value. I tried putting `finish()` after I pass between activities, still same result. I tried putting `nohistory` in manifest and same deal.
This is the code where I go to `firstlog` from maps

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this,FirstLog.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", 1);
startActivity(intent);
```

This is where I go back to maps from `firstlog`

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences("isfirsttime", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID");
    if(s=="1")
    {
        sharedPref.edit().putBoolean("isfirsttime",false);
        Log.i("firsttime","NOT FIRST TIME");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i("firsttime","FIRST TIME");
        Log.i("firsttime","intent value equals: " + s);
    }
    if(sharedPref.getBoolean("isfirsttime",true)) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, explanationscreen.class));
        finish();
    }
    else
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is you are passing **int** in intent and retrieving a **String**
You should use `int s = getIntent().getIntExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", defaultValue)` instead of

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID");
```

code:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences("isfirsttime", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(getIntent().hasExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID"){
            int s = getIntent().getIntExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID",1);
            if(s==1)
            {
                sharedPref.edit().putBoolean("isfirsttime",false);
                Log.i("firsttime","NOT FIRST TIME");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("firsttime","FIRST TIME");
                Log.i("firsttime","intent value equals: " + s);
            }
}
            if(sharedPref.getBoolean("isfirsttime",true)) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, explanationscreen.class));
                finish();
            }
            else
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
```

Comment: Even with getIntExtra?

Comment: Tried copying the code one by one and it did work but only because you set the default value to 1 which should be 0 as 1 is the value being passed from the maps activity. Right when I changed it to 0 I saw that it's always 0. I tried to check it in the oncreate function and same thing (this code is held inside a button listener) shouldn't be a problem with other pieces of code as I tried checking it first thing it does and sending the data first thing it does in the other activity. I think I'm missing a step somewhere...

Comment: Default value is used to avoid null pointer exception you can change it to 0 or -1, and you should share some more code from other activities so we can figure out the problem

Comment: Posted more code in another commend above you. Problem with putting it one though is that I only want it one when I come from the mapsactivity anyways code above.

Comment: Ok if you want it only when coming from MapActivity you should put all this code in a if block 
if(getIntent().hasExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID"))

Comment: if(getIntent().hasExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID){
int s = getIntent().getIntExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID",1); if(s==1) { sharedPref.edit().putBoolean("isfirsttime",false); Log.i("firsttime","NOT FIRST TIME"); } else { Log.i("firsttime","FIRST TIME"); Log.i("firsttime","intent value equals: " + s); }
}

Comment: My pleasure sir

Answer (score 1):

Here is issue, you are passing an `Integer` and trying to get `String` dude?
Use this when getting Int extra.

```
 int i = getIntent().getIntExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID");
```

**You should beware of type cast as android provide different methods for different data types.**

Comment: Then error is sure in your code or flow. You should post full code at least of two activities which are passing bundle

Comment: I think you are not clear about passing bundles. Here is one answer i posted a while ago. which you should read to be clear about intents